# Como comparar una fecha tipo Date en java?

Tags: java, jsf, date

tengo la siguiente tabla, la cual muestra una columna llamada vigencia

```html
<p:dataTable id="horarios1" rendered="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.muestraHistorial}" var="consultaHorario" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.listNivelesPersona2}">
  <p:column headerText="Ubi" style="width: 50px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Horario" style="width: 50px;">

  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Vigencia">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecInicioNivel}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText> -
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

que contiene dos campos fecha inicio y fecha fin, entonces hay algunos registros que en el campo de fechaFin pinta la fecha 3000-12-31 00:00:00.0, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando un registro traiga esa fecha, no muestre nada en el campo fechaFin, simplemenete pinte una 
fecha de inicio 12/04/2016-

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
listNivelesPersona2 = nivelesPersonaService.findNivelesPersonaConsultaHorario(cvePersona);

    System.out.println("PRUEBA FECHA FIN \n" +listNivelesPersona2.get(0).getFecFinNivel());

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("3000-12-31");

        if(listNivelesPersona2.get(0).getFecFinNivel().equals(date1)){
            System.out.println("SON IGUALES");
        }


    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NivelesPersonaComponentImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

hice una variable tipo date1 y le pase esa fecha, entonces quiero comparar la fecha que viene de mi lista con date1 y si son iguales, que muestre otra variable tipo date pero vacia
y es que hice la prueba pero no hace nada, no entra al system que dice son iguales
o cuales la mejor forma para comparar fechas, como le puedo hacer??

Answer (score 0):

Si el valor que recupera `getFecFinNivel()` es también `Date()`

```
listNivelesPersona2.get(0).getFecFinNivel().compareTo(date1)
```

Mas info en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) del `Date().compareTo()`

Comment: ya lo hice, if(listNivelesPersona2.get(0).getFecFinNivel().compareTo(date1)){
            
            }    pero sale error, me dice que int no puede ser convertido a boolean y muestra Unparseable date: "3000-12-31"

Comment: en la documentacion puedes ver que el metodo Date().compareTo() regresa un entero. Si quieres saber si las fechas son iguales, compara con el numero 0, que es lo que regresa compareTo() cuando las fechas son iguales. if (listNivelesPersona2.get(0).getFecFinNivel().compareTo(date1) == 0) { // son la misma fecha }